# Can this Ruby on Rails code be optimized or improved at all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization

The code:

```
user = ... #pretend it has a value :)
instances = Array.new
Product.all.each do |product|
    productInstance = ProductInstance.new
    productInstance.user = user
    productInstance.product = product
    instances.push(productInstance)
end
```

`Product` and `ProductInstance` are both Rails models. Is a for-each loop on `Product.all` going to be slow? Just wondering if there is a better way of doing this...

Comment: The `product` variable inside your block is instance of Product, so you made another model just to store Product and User instances together? Maybe it is faster to do not drag entire model with all attributes to productInstance, just put only product_id and user_id into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somthing like this should work.

```
instances = Product.all.map do |product|
    productInstance = ProductInstance.new(:user => user,:product => product)
end
```

or even

```
instances = Product.all.map do |product|
    ProductInstance.new(:user => user,:product => product)
end
```

For Mass assignment restriction you can try something like

```
instances = Product.all.map do |product|
    ProductInstance.new {|instance| instance.user = user;instance.product = product}
end
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this if `ProductInstance.user` and `ProductInstance.product` are not mass-assignable (i.e. can't be passed into `ProductInstance.new()`)?

Comment: @Dr.SteveBrule Please check the updated answer, hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

Never iterate on your whole collection at one time.

Maybe this will work fine on your development box, and maybe on you fresh production.

But when your application gets popular and your DB will have serious amount of records, you will get time and memory problems with your code.

Use for example http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_in_batches and learn how garbage collection works http://timetobleed.com/garbage-collection-slides-from-la-ruby-conference/

```
Product.find_in_batches do |products|
  products.each do |product|
    productInstance = ProductInstance.new
    productInstance.user = user
    productInstance.product = product
    instances.push(productInstance)  
  end
end
```

Comment: this is by far most valuable answer in terms of performance. worth mentioning that there is `#find_each` method that gets rid of code nestiness.

Answer (score 1):

I'd only change `each` to `map` (it's more idiomatic).

```
instances = Product.all.map do |product|
    productInstance = ProductInstance.new
    productInstance.user = user
    productInstance.product = product
    productInstance
end
```

Answer (score 1):

first in your `ProductInstance` model add

```
attr_accessible :user, :product
```

and then

```
instances = Product.all.map {|product| ProductInstance.create(:user => user, :product => product)}
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done like this also

```
 instances = Product.all.map {|product| ProductInstance.new(:user => user, :product => product)}
```